# Add space between text and number SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have an `ID` column in my database which contains values like this:

```
AB1234GF
```

I want to add a space to these values like this:

```
AB1234 GF
```

How can this be achieved?

I tried substring and split method, but because the length of each `ID` is different, it is not working.

Comment: What data type is the column?

Comment: And do you want a space between `AB1234`?

Comment: Nvarchar is the datatype and I want space between abcd1234 and gf

Comment: Well, when inserting values into the table it's pretty straightforward you just give the column the value ```'AB1234 GF'```. And if you want to change the ones you have you can use the update command

Answer (score 0):

We can use `PATINDEX()` here:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(col, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9][A-Z]%', col)) + ' ' +
    SUBSTRING(col, PATINDEX('%[0-9][A-Z]%', col) + 1, LEN(col)) AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo